# Recursion to find the maximum profit

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

Given a array of numbers representing the stock prices of a company in chronological order, write a function that calculates the maximum profit you could have made from buying and selling that stock.

```
k = [1, 3, 2, 8, 4, 10] # given number of stocks


def max_profit(price, start, end):

    if (end <= start): # If the stocks can't be bought
        return 0

    profit = 0
    for i in range(start, end):
        for j in range(i + 1, end + 1):
            if (price[j] > price[i]):
                curr_profit = price[j] - price[i] + max_profit(
                    price, start, i - 1) + max_profit(price, j + 1, end)

                profit = max(profit, curr_profit)
    return profit


n = len(k)
print(max_profit(k, 0, n - 1))
```

prints `14`

This is a sample code for finding the maximum profit for a given stocks. I am having issue with one line only.

`curr_profit = price[j] - price[i] + max_profit(price, start, i - 1) + max_profit(price, j + 1, end)`

What is this recursion  `max_profit(price, start, i - 1) + max_profit(price, j + 1, end)` doing?

Thanks in advance

Also instead of using `i` or `j` in the recursion, why we used `i-1` and `j+1`

Comment: Your question aside, recursion sounds like a terrible way to approach the problem.

Comment: The code is buying the stock at `i` and selling the stock at `j`. Then it adds the best profit from [the blue and green regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agDjw.png).